# EnumPrinters() + error RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE (1722)

Tags: winapi, printing

I am working on a sample to get the list of printer connected to machine. For that I am using EnumPrinters() API to get the printers. Randomly it gives the error RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE (1722). I tried to search in the net, but  I could not get the solution.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you calling EnumPrinters (hint - post the code)?

For some modes of API invocation, the local system will RPC to the target servers in turn - this uses RPC, so you can get RPC errors back.  You may be able to get the info you need via a less heavyweight call that uses different parameters to EnumPrinters.

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162692%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> when EnumPrinters is called with a
>   level 2 (PRINTER_INFO_2) data
>   structure, it performs an OpenPrinter
>   call on each remote connection. If a
>   remote connection is down, or the
>   remote server no longer exists, or the
>   remote printer no longer exists, the
>   function must wait for RPC to time out
>   and consequently fail the OpenPrinter
>   call. This can take a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently with my Windows 10 PC. I spent a lot of time with debugging of EnumPrinters, with all different sorts of levels, but nothing worked and I always got the error `RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE (1722)`. It turned out that something has stopped the Spooler service and even after a reboot it was disabled. After enabling the Spooler service, everything worked. You can notice the Spooler service failure by looking at the Win10 printer settings: All printers would show "not connected", even Print to PDF.